# plotting surface of a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix t with three columns x,y and z that contain radius, angle and signal values from my simulation, respectively:

```
t = [
x   y    z
10  0   -1
10  2   -11
10  3   -10
20  5   -25
20  7   -100
20  20   -101
20  3   -12
30  12   -104
.    .     .
.    .     .
.    .     .
]
```

as you can see, the values have not any order, and also the first column (x) has a lot of repeated values. What I want is to make a nice surface that shows the fluctuations of the signal values (z column) in respect to the radius and angle values (x and y columns). 
I searched a lot and I tried almost every suggestions in the site, but always faced with errors like data dimensions must agree.
Can someone help? thanks in advance.

Comment: It's probably a good start if you convert your data to cartesian coordinates (see pol2cart)

Answer (score 1):

You can use your available points to get interpolated points on a regular grid and then create a surface plot as described [here](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/visualize/representing-a-matrix-as-a-surface.html#f0-9140):

```
xs = linspace(min(t(:,1)), max(t(:,1)), 50);
ys = linspace(min(t(:,2)), max(t(:,2)), 50);
[x, y] = meshgrid(xs, ys);
f = scatteredInterpolant(t(:,1), t(:,2), t(:,3));
z = f(x, y);
surf(x, y, z);
```

Another way would be to triangulate your existing points and use [`trisurf`](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/trisurf.html):

```
tri = delaunay(t(:,1), t(:,2));
trisurf(tri, t(:,1), t(:,2), t(:,3));
```

Comment: still no go. I get the same error: ??? Error using ==> surf at 78
Data dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> x at 8
surf(X, Y, z);

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need:

```
M = [10, 0, -1
10, 2, -11
10, 3, -10
20, 5 , -25
20, 7 , -100
20, 20, -101
20, 3, -12
30, 12, -104];


[xq,yq] = meshgrid(min(M(:,1)):1:max(M(:,1)), min(M(:,2)):1:max(M(:,2)));
vq = griddata(M(:,1),M(:,2),M(:,3),xq,yq);

surf(xq,yq,vq)
```

In order to plot a surface you need to decide what the value is between the used points. In this case I have used `griddata` to interpolate.

Comment: I get this error : ??? Error using ==> griddata>linear at 164
Error computing Delaunay triangulation. The sample datapoints may be
collinear.

Error in ==> griddata at 133
    zi = linear(x,y,z,xi,yi);

Error in ==> x at 4
vq = griddata(t(:,1),t(:,2),t(:,3),xq,yq);

Comment: I did have an old line in the code, but I don't get your error. Do you get it with this data or with your real data? Otherwise I would think it may be the case that one xy pair occurs more than ones. If so, you will need to do some cleanup first.

Comment: I get the error with my actual data. So is there any function or trick to do the cleanup, or I have to do this manually? Thanks for your time.